# Data initializing with promises

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, ionic3

I really struggle with data initializing and promises. I am using Ionic 3 with Angular and Ionic storage, but my question is mainly related to how promises operate.

Basically I would like to achieve the following:

- when my app starts it should use the local storage collection
- if the local storage collection does not exist or is empty, create a new one with http
- if the http fails, create a collection with local data.

My solution so far:

```
getNewsItems():Promise<any> {
  return this.storage.get(this.newsKey).then((data) => {
    if(data == null)
    { 
      return (this.buildNewsItemsViaHttp());
    } else {
      return (data);
    }
  });
}

private buildNewsItemsViaHttp(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get('some/url/to/fetch/data')
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.newsCollection = data;
          this.storage.set(this.newsKey, this.newsCollection);
          resolve(this.newsCollection);
        },
        (err) => {
          resolve (this.buildNewsItemsViaLocalJSON());
        }
      );
});
}

private buildNewsItemsViaLocalJSON() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get('assets/data/newsCollectionLocal.json')
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.newsCollection = data;
          this.storage.set(this.newsKey, this.newsCollection);
          resolve(this.newsCollection);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
});}
```

I don't like some parts of it, for example returning a promise inside a promise - is this actually an issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean solution could be using async\await methods:

```
async buildNewsItemsViaHttp(){
   return await this.http.get()....
}

async buildNewsItemsViaLocalJSON(){
   return await this.http.get()....
}

async getNewsItems(){
   return await this.storage.get()...
}

async getItems(){
     return ((await this.getNewsItems()) || (await this.buildNewsItemsViaLocalJSON()) || (await this.buildNewsItemsViaHttp()));
}
```

usage:

```
const items = await this.getItems();
```

You can optimize the resources, cache them and return them in each function.
Example:

```
async buildNewsItemsViaHttp(){
   let result = cache.get(); // todo

   if(!result){
        result = await this.http.get()...
        cache.set(result)
   }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: But consider what happens if the promises should follow their error path. Unless errors are caught at each stage and falsy value is forced down the success path, then the flow in  `(await x() || (await y()) || (await z()))` won't be as you would (generally) want. Compare the outcome of "Test 1" with "Test 2" [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bcmoL7yr/).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - This is not production code, it's a piece of code that shows the concept. You should handle errors in each method by using try catch. also, you can modify the `getItems()` method to not work with or commands.

Comment: But what if your const is at the top level which does not allow await?